# Populate Table from Table Spatialite

Tags: spatialite

I am trying to populate a column in a table from another table using Spatialite.  My query will not populate the column, and I can't seem to identify what is wrong.  I modeled the query from the following post: http://www.surfaces.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/SL_update3.png

What I would like to achieve is to have the corresponding values from lu_grid.gridid to populate lu_geophotos.gridid where lu_geophotos intersects with lu_grid. (A column in a point layer should get the values from a polygon where the points intersect the polygon)

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE lu_geophotos SET gridid = (SELECT GRIDID
FROM lu_grid AS s
 WHERE ST_WITHIN (s.Geometry, lu_geophotos.Geometry)
 AND s.ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID
  FROM SpatialIndex
  WHERE f_table_name = 'lu_grid' AND search_frame = lu_geophotos.Geometry)
);
```

[image]

Comment: What does ```SELECT GRIDID FROM lu_grid WHERE ST_Within(lu_grid.Geometry, lu_geophotos.Geometry) LIMIT 5;``` give you? The spatial index probably isn't needed because you probably don't have enough entries (10K+) to make it worth the effort.

Comment: It returns an error.  SQL error: no such column: lu_geophotos.Geometry
The table and the geometry exists

Comment: Sorry. ```SELECT lu_geophotos.GRIDID FROM lu_geophotos, lu_grid WHERE ST_Within(lu_grid.Geometry, lu_geophotos.Geometry) LIMIT 5;```

Comment: Thanks Brad. It executed, but nothing is being written to the table.  Its the same thing I was noticing with my code

Comment: That wasn't mean to update anything, just to show matching records. What do the matches look like? If none, your data doesn't look the way you think it does. What do ```SELECT AsEwkt(Geometry) FROM lu_grid LIMIT 5;``` and ```SELECT AsEwkt(Geometry) FROM lu_geophotos LIMIT 5;``` show? You might want to add that to the question.

Comment: How did this go? Still an issue?

Comment: Sorry Brad, got real busy. That worked, it selected five column. But how would I populate one table from another?

Comment: The intersection of points to polygons isn't the problem, I can do that with the following, its the populating the results into a point column:
SELECT
     f.filepath, f.gridid,
     g.gridid
FROM
     lu_geophotos AS f JOIN
     lu_grid AS g
     ON (ST_Intersects(f.Geometry, g.Geometry))

Comment: Consider updating the question with this, and show the data.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the values won't populate from one table to the other

Comment: Then can you rework the question and add the sample data and results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue related to the query. I removed everything after ST_Within, and re-ordered the layers (I had the grid first, and the points second, and they should have been reversed). See the code below:

UPDATE lu_geophotos

SET gridid = (SELECT GRIDID FROM lu_grid

WHERE ST_Within(lu_geophotos.Geometry, lu_grid.Geometry))